# PHP function to send form data

Tags: php, forms, function, email, post

I want to add a function to the end of my included file (code below) that will email the POST data that it validates. I have tried different ways to do  this but to no avail? Everything is validating no problem but that is all! I basically have a form that validates and does nothing apart from that!

I just need a function to be added that will email the POST data:

```
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $addDateErr = $nameErr = $emailErr = $subjectErr = $messageErr = $questionErr = "";
    $addDate = $name = $email = $subject = $message = $WebSearch = $SocialMedia =  $WordOfMouth = $Other ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
//Date
   if (empty($_POST["addDate"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["addDate"]);}

//Name
    if (empty($_POST["name"]))
    {$nameErr = "Name is required";}
    else
    {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name))
    {
    $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
    }
    }

//Email
   if (empty($_POST["email"]))
   {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
   else
   {
   $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
   if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
   {
   $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
   }
   }

//Subject
   if (empty($_POST["subject"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["subject"]);}

//Message
   if (empty($_POST["message"]))
   {$messageErr = "A message is required";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["message"]);}

//Question
    if (isset($_POST['Question']))
    {
    $menuVar = $_POST['Question'];
    } else {
    $menuVar = "----------";}
}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Just concatenate the data into a string, and call `mail()`. If you want help correcting the problems in your code, please show what you tried.

Comment: @Barman, To be honest I am totally new to PHP and have spent the past 3 days putting this code together. I did two php courses over a three month period but it is really tricky for me and I get totally confused. I got a lot of the code from the w3 school site and used my css knowledge to produce the form. I am sure that this is a two minute fix for someone who knows what they are doing with PHP. I have tried and tried to the extent that I am considering just taking out the validation as I don't understand forms. I have also tried swfmailer and phpmailer but again just got more confused!

Comment: If you've taken two PHP courses and this is still too complicated for you, you may not be cut out for programming.

Comment: I agree totally. I think that it is hard for me as It's not my line of work. I picked up css quite well but that is easy! The other problem is that I am self taught. I learned with video tutorials.

Comment: I am very sad to hear that. I am not looking for a free coding service at all. I have been stuck here staring my computer for days trying to work this out. One helpful line of code or a point in the right direction is all I wanted. I have spent hours teaching photoshop to other on line via youtube etc. that is my field. It's nice to help others in what we are good at and that is what forums are all about. If it is to complicated then its fine, I thought it would be just one line of code. I have asked a programmer for help and am waiting for a reply, I am happy to pay for this fix : (

Comment: @Barmar, I ended up hiring a programer and he fixed this for me using phpmailer. I'm going back to learn php more! I realize after posting this question that even with the help I was not able to fix it myself. Php is complicated in my opinion! Probably because I am just not very good at it! Anyway thank you for your willingness to help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably will want some sort of library that does the job of sending the e-mail for you.

Here are some:

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

http://swiftmailer.org/

http://sendgrid.com/

Comment: @Margaret, have anyone here answered your question? Consider choosing one of ours answers as correct.

Comment: Actually your solution was the one that was used! phpmailer was the best solution in the end. I ended up paying a programmer to do this for me because I did try to do the phpmailer myself but again it was just to confusing for my limited php knowledge.... I thought this would be a quick fix but it was not at all! My hired programmer used phpmailer. Thank you so much for your help : )

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to send emails with php:

```
mail("youremail@uptoyou.com", "Subject", "Message", "From:sender@test.com");
```

In your case you could do something like:

```
mail("receiver@test.com", $_POST["subject"], "Message:" . $_POST["message"] . "Question:" . $_POST['Question'], "From:" . $_POST["email"]);
```

Comment: I think his actual question is about constructing the message, not about sending the mail.

Comment: Well constructing the message is just adding all the strings together as you like it. I guess he knows how to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your help here guys, I think that the answer is that I need to study more. I think this forum is more for professionals than learners. Sorry if my question appeared demanding. I will go back to my courses and hopefully learn more that I have already...

Comment: This site is for everyone. I'm not a professional, this is just a hobby of mine. The answer is very easy, you have all your variables set up already, so all that is left is to put them in this mail function. I'll edit my post to show it.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time here ledidhuyvetter : )

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign all your validated form inputs to different variables; for some reason, you reused `$comment` for several of them. Once you have them in variables, you can do something like this:

```
$mail_body = <<<EOM
Name: $name
Email: $email
Subject: $subject
Date: $date
Question: $question
Message: $message
EOM ;

mail("youraddress@yourdomain.com", "Form submission", $mail_body, "From: someaddress@yourdomain.com");
```

Comment: thank you for your help everyone. I tried these solutions but just could not understand the code enough to get it working! I think the whole thing is just out of my depth so I actually ended up paying a programmer to fix this for me. He was great and I was very happy to have this fixed after days of trying to fix it myself! I think I should just stick to css until I have learned php a whole lot more!